# Link more categories/sub-categories to 1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

For sure someone asked it before, but i don't know how to call it. So, that's why i asking it again.

In my menu i have different categories like:
Women
Men
accessory

And in the categories there are sub-categories in Women like accessory. Is there a possible way that the accesory can be the same page? So it links to each other?

Hope you can help me guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `Accessory` & `Women/Accessory` will be two separated category pages. They will have different URLs like `/accessory.html` & `/women/accessory.html`. I don't recommend to force the same URL for both. In `url_rewrite` table the url_key must be unique, so you can have problems.

You can assign prodcuts to both categoreis or do redirect from `/women/accessory.html` to `/accessory.html`

Comment: Np, you can mark check icon at my post if I helped you :)